# Running fastapi within class

Tags: python, fastapi

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

# 2. Create the app object
app = FastAPI()

# 3. Index route, opens automatically on http://127.0.0.1:8000
class RunModel():
    @app.get('/')
    def index(self):
        return {'message': 'Hello'}

    @app.get('/predict')
    def get_res(self, feat1: float, feat2:float):
        res = feat1 + feat2
        return {'result': f'{res:.4f}'}

run_model = RunModel()
# 5. Run the API with uvicorn
#    Will run on http://127.0.0.1:8000
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
```

When I run this first of all I get the error (in terminal and not browser) `422 Unprocessable Entity`. Next thing is when I go to the http://localhost:8000/docs it seems like it is expecting me to enter 3 values for `/predict` route, the two features as expected **and self**. So the question is how can I use this class structure and still use fastapi (i.e. ignore `self`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use class based views from [**fastapi-utils**](https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/class-based-views/).

Create a router using InferringRouter, then decorate the class with `cbv` object. Inside the class, you can start creating your endpoints with your `router` object.

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi_utils.cbv import cbv
from fastapi_utils.inferring_router import InferringRouter


app = FastAPI()
router = InferringRouter()


@cbv(router)
class RunModel:
    @router.get("/")
    def index(self):
        return {"message": "Hello"}

    @router.get("/predict")
    def get_res(self, feat1: float, feat2: float):
        res = feat1 + feat2
        return {"result": f"{res:.4f}"}


app.include_router(router)
```

Comment: whaat about using @repeat_every inside a class method?

Comment: Consider using the forked and maintained version of fastapi_utils lib: https://github.com/yuval9313/FastApi-RESTful. It has some fixed issues.

Comment: FastApi utils are not maintained for more than 8 months already

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

class Settings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_version = "v1"
        self.api_name = "my_api"
        self.db = "some db"
        self.logger = "configured logger"
        self.DEBUG = True


class MyApi:
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings
        self._fastapi = FastAPI(
            version=self.settings.api_version,
        )
        self._fastapi.add_api_route(
            path="/",
            endpoint=self.index,
            methods=["GET"]
        )

        self._fastapi.add_api_route(
            path="/predict",
            endpoint=self.get_res,
            methods=["POST"]
        )

    async def index(self):
        if self.settings.DEBUG:
            pass
        return {"message": "Hello"}

    async def get_res(self, feat1: float, feat2: float):
        """
        You are able to access the settings
        """
        res = feat1 + feat2
        return {"result": f"{res:.4f}", "api_version": self.settings.api_version}

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if hasattr(self._fastapi, attr):
            return getattr(self._fastapi, attr)
        else:
            raise AttributeError(f"{attr} not exist")

    async def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return await self._fastapi(*args, **kwargs)


settings = Settings()
app = MyApi(settings)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, all the packages wrapping FastAPI in classes, like [fastapi-utils](https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-utils/) and [fastapi-class](https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-class/) seem to be deprecated, so I would suggest using `FastAPI` directly.

The underlying problem is, that FastAPI uses decorators like `@app.get(...)`, which don't work well in classes.

## Inheritance

So based on Kostiantyn's answer, I have written a little example using `FastAPI` as base class:

```py
from typing import Any

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse, JSONResponse


class App(FastAPI):
    def __init__(self, **extra: Any):
        super().__init__(**extra)

        self.add_api_route("/", self.get_root, methods=["GET"], include_in_schema=False)
        self.add_api_route("/version", self.get_version, methods=["GET"])

    @staticmethod
    async def get_root() -> HTMLResponse:
        return HTMLResponse('<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=\'/docs\'" />')

    async def get_version(self) -> JSONResponse:
        return JSONResponse({"FastAPI version": self.version})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/q/65446591/5538913"
    app = App(
        title="FastAPI from class",
        description=f"Source: <a href='{url}'>Stack Overflow</a>",
    )
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

This way the `App` and its routes can be configured easily, you can even define websockets with `self.add_api_websocket_route` etc.

---

## Composition

Another approach would be to define a `serve` method in your class and implement the endpoints there:

```py
import asyncio
from typing import Optional

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, JSONResponse


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.version = "0.0.1"

        url = "https://stackoverflow.com/q/65446591/5538913"
        self.app = FastAPI(
            title="FastAPI from class",
            description=f"Source: <a href='{url}'>Stack Overflow</a>",
        )
        self.serving_task: Optional[asyncio.Task] = None

    async def serve(self):
        app: FastAPI = self.app

        @app.get("/", include_in_schema=False)
        async def _get_root():
            """
            Redirect to /docs
            """
            return HTMLResponse('<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=\'/docs\'" />')

        @app.get("/version")
        async def _get_version() -> JSONResponse:
            return JSONResponse({"MyClass version": self.version, "FastAPI version": app.version})

        # serve
        config = uvicorn.Config(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
        server = uvicorn.Server(config)
        await server.serve()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    instance = MyClass()
    asyncio.run(instance.serve())
```